# how to pass url to img tag using jinja with flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to pass url to img tag in html with jinja using flask

Html: here row.2 contains name of the image and images is a folder in same directory.

```
{% for row in students %}

<img src="{{url_for('images', filename = '{{row.2}}' )}}" 
 alt= "{{ row.2 }}" width="120" height="90" />
```

It Was showing me an error :
Could not build url for endpoint 'images' with values ['filename']

when i print row.2 it printing the name of image - like: Test.png

Comment: try removing the inverted comma from the filename.. make it {{ row.2 }}.. since you are expecting a value there

Comment: @sarthaNegi i have seen by changing that but its return some other error like got{'0',} something like that , how to change static path to pass url !!

Comment: is images the root folder or is it inside another folder... take hints from this instance.. <img src="{{url_for('static',filename='images/logo.png')}}"

Comment: Yes i have tried this, it was retrieving the image but , how give file name from db like src="{{url_for('image',filename='images/{{row.2}}' )}}"

Comment: Thankyou bro , problem solved <img src="/static/images/{{ row.2 }}" width="120" height="90" alt="">

Comment: i am trying to assign url through an method but its not working so for now i have done above code

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use variables directly in `{{ }}` like you did in Python:

`<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=row.2) }}" alt= "{{ row.2 }}" width="120" height="90" />`

Comment: this was passing an error _Could not build url for endpoint 'images' with values ['filename']. Did you mean 'insert' instead?

Comment: How do you define the `image` function? Maybe what you actually want is `static`.